# Fill missing combinations in a dataframe

Tags: r

My example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
 REGION = c("REGION A", "REGION A", "REGION B"), 
 CATEGORY = c("A", "B", "B"), 
 VALUE1 = c(2,3,4),
 VALUE2 = c(1,2,3)
)
```

Result:

```
  REGION    CATEGORY VALUE1 VALUE2
1 REGION A   A             2     1
2 REGION A   B             3     2
3 REGION B   B             4     3
```

Now I want that every combination of REGION and CATEGORY that is not considered in the data set is filled with a VALUE1 and VALUE2 of 0. The result of this `df` should be:

```
      REGION   CATEGORY VALUE1 VALUE2
    1 REGION A  A          2      1
    2 REGION A  B          3      2
    3 REGION B  A          4      3
    4 REGION B  B          0      0
```

I already wrote a big function for it, that generates a dynamic string with for-loops, but I have the feeling that there is a much simpler way to do it with only a few lines of code. I guess I am thinking much too complicated. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your result output is either missing the Category value, or Region is different to your output data - for the combinations, maybe `expand.grid()` will help.

Comment: In base R, as mentioned, with the current example, d do `dfNew <- merge(df, expand.grid(df[1:2]), all=TRUE); df[is.na(df)] <- 0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `complete` from tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(complete(df,REGION,CATEGORY,fill=list(VALUE1=0,VALUE2=0)))
```

Output:

```
    REGION CATEGORY VALUE1 VALUE2
1 REGION A        A      2      1
2 REGION A        B      3      2
3 REGION B        A      0      0
4 REGION B        B      4      3
```

If there are many variables, you could also just do `as.data.frame(complete(df,REGION,CATEGORY))` and replace the `NA`'s afterwards.

Hope this helps!